# Ошибка Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите пожалуйста. Столкнулся с ошибкой

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hp1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in 
__call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Hp1\PycharmProjects\untitled14\main.py", line 214, in image
for i in len(str(filename)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Делаю цикл который меняет сторонами слеши. Сама функция где происходит эта ошибка:

```
def image():
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Картинки", "*.jpg *.png")])
    for i in len(str(filename)):
        print(i)
    lbl.configure(text=str(filename))
```

Сразу спасибо за помощь.

Comment: вместо `for i in len(str(filename)):` надо `for i in range(len(str(filename))):`

Comment: Чтобы слеши поменять, можно просто замену через `replace` сделать: `filename = filename.replace('/', '\\')`.

Comment: Но если следовать вашей мысли, то скорее всего вам надо  получить несколько картинок и тогда вам нужна вот эта функция `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(**options)` и следовательно вызов будет выглядеть так `filenames = askopenfiles(...)` и тогда   `for imageFile in filenames: ...`